# are there books that cover game menus and preloaders for AS3 flash games?

Tags: flash, actionscript, menu, preloader

I'm aware there are tutorials online that cover how to make game menus and preloaders for AS3 flash games, but I've found that books are more in-depth for certain topics. Are there books with sections that cover the process of making a preloader and menus for an AS3 flash game?

My ultimate goal is to implement a preloader AND game menus without referring to the timeline.

specific book titles would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you serious? :) A preloader is 5 lines of code... if you don't understand that you need a different book... and even if you are dynamically loading data it's still not enough for a book, it's maybe 30-50 additional lines in that case if not less (done properly)...

Comment: If the book only had a few pages dedicated to those parts, I would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preloaders are a pretty easy topic to cover.

Here's what you need to know:

1. `root.loaderInfo` - The [`LoaderInfo`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) object associated with `root`
2. [`bytesLoaded`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#bytesLoaded)
3. [`bytesTotal`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#bytesTotal)

The latter two being properties of `LoaderInfo`.

You'll be able to use these two properties to work out a percentage that represents how much of the SWF has been loaded. Generally this would be handled in an `ENTER_FRAME`, like this:

```
var percent:Number = 0;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _preload);
function _preload(e:Event):void
{
    percent = root.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded / root.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;

    if(percent >= 1)
    {
        // do stuff once preloader is complete such as gotoAndStop(2)

        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _preload);
    }
}
```

You could work with [`ProgressEvent.PROGRESS`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#event%3aprogress) if you wanted to as well, I've just preferred using `ENTER_FRAME`.

Comment: I think I should clarify that my ultimate goal is to implement preloader AND menus without resorting to the timeline. Is that possible?

Comment: Yep.. Initialize a preloader in the document class and once it's finished, de-initialize it and create a new menu.

Answer (score 0):

There is two great tutorials for making menu systems for flash games with as3 code:

http://asgamer.com/2009/making-a-complete-flash-game-menus-ui-screens-or-windows

http://redgrim.com/tag/as3/